# Error with dynamical allocation of 2 pointers

Tags: c, malloc, free

I came across something a bit weird that I couldn't understand when i was messing with the malloc function.

I declared 2 pointers and allocated memory for them as follow:

```
struct User {
    char *username, *password;
};

int main() {
    struct User user;
    user.username = user.password = malloc (50);
    scanf ("%s %s", user.username, user.password);
    printf ("%s %s\n", user.username, user.password);

    free (user.username);
    free (user.password);

    return 0;
```

The `scanf()` works perfectly as well as the `printf()`.
However, when it comes to `free()` an error shows up. When I only free one of the two pointers the error doesn't occur. I know this has to do with the `user.username = user.password` part of the code but I don't understand what is really going on.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You call `malloc` once, why do you think you need to `free` twice?

Comment: `user.username = user.password = malloc (50);` - One allocation, two `free`s - One problem. Problem two - `user.username` and `user.passsword` will point to the same place!

Comment: Doesn't it call malloc for both variables ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @EdHeal since it points to the same place, how come the second part of the scanf (user.password) doesn't erase what was written in the first one (user.username) ?

Comment: It does - Try it. Enter `A B` and what does `pirntf` display?

Comment: You're right I didn't read correctly at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment returns the value that has been assigned. So in your case user.username und user.password will point to the same memory location (the one returned by malloc). When you call free() on both of them the same location is freed twice, which causes the error.

Try allocating two different blocks of memory:

```
user.username = malloc (50);
user.password = malloc (50);
```